# Found some code that Sort using Arrays.sort()

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I was trying to make a java program that solved using the Genetic Algorithm in Java. I was having trouble in sorting the fitness value of chromosomes, and then I found this code that works perfectly with my other code:

```
public void sortChromosomeByFitness(){
    Arrays.sort(chrom,(chrom1,chrom2) -> {

        int flag = 0;
        if(chrom1.getFitness() > chrom2.getFitness())
            flag=-1;
        else if (chrom1.getFitness() < chrom2.getFitness())
            flag=1;
        return flag;

    });
}
```

Can anyone help me to explain the meaning of the code? especially the  Arrays.sort(chrom,(chrom1,chrom2) -> , and what are the flag are for? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) for the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. The `flag` is just the value the [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) method normally returns.

It could even be replaced by `Comparator.comparing(Chromosome::getFitness)` if the class is called `Chromosome`.